# How do you open an excel file and then click a dialog box before reading the file, from a python script?

Tags: python, tkinter, macros, openpyxl

I get these excel files at work sent to me that I am trying to read from python to automate. The problem is that the full contents of the file are not loaded from simply opening the file. Once you open the file there is a dialog box that pops up where I can click "Show Content" and then all the content will load.

I need some way from python to open the excel file, click this button, and then read the contents. Is this possible? I have the code to simply create a tkinter gui prompt to upload a file and to then read from that file with openpyxl. I just need a way to open the file, then click the button.

Edit: Also closing the Excel prompt will allow the content to load, so I can either click the button on the prompt or close the prompt, but I need to do this with python, then wait, then read the sheets.

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

def open_file():
    file = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes = [('Excel Files', '*.xlsx *.xlsm *.csv')])
    wb = load_workbook(filename = file.name)
    root.destroy()
    pass
    # I will write code to check for certain values in the file and match here

btn = Button(root, text='Open', command = open_file)
btn.pack(side='top')

mainloop()
```

Comment: That is a security setting that prevents you from getting owned by malicious Excel files. Trying to automate the GUI is always the wrong way. In this case, openpyxl can pull data from Excel files without opening them in excel at all. Why do you need to open it with Excel? What happens in Excel? Is it running some VBA or getting data from another place?

Comment: So a company sends me excel documents that have VBA embedded and that VBA code is password protected. When you open the excel file there are only some sheets and a dialog box. I can click exit or click "show" and then I will have access to the sheets I need. I do not know VBA or what the code is, I believe the data is not accessible until this prompt is clicked. I can try to extract it without opening the file, I did not know this was possible, I thought you had to first load it.

Comment: It is possible it is getting data from another place or it is hidden in some way, but I have no way of seeing that code unfortunately.

Comment: I am going to try to learn VBA enough to recreate the scenario on something that I would be able to post. When you say it is for security, how so? Is this ActiveX controls?

Comment: Update: I can retrieve values. I just cannot change values in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to read and write to the file without opening it, this bypassed the error I was receiving.

Comment: Use the checkmark to the left of this answer to declare this question closed. You get points for answering your own question.